# Google Auth Javascript API messing with Angular Material Components

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, google-api-js-client

I have an Angularv5 project with a number of Angular Material components. I've successfully set up sign in via google using `gapi.auth2`. The problem is that, it appears, using `gapi.auth2` *inside* an angular component largely destroys Angular's ability to render (official) material components. By this I mean, *after* successfully authenticating with `gapi`, clicking a `mat-checkbox` no longer selects the checkbox. `matInput` elements cannot be interacted with. Mat overlay elements appear in random areas of the screen, rather than tethered to their parents appropriately (e.g. `mat-select`'s overlay). Before authentication, there is no problem.

If I move the `gapi.auth2.authorize` code outside of a component and into the `index.html` header, and simply trigger it to run after page load, then everything runs smoothly. Unfortunately, I'd like to trigger authentication from within my app... I tried using `NgZone` to run the authentication code outside of Angular's zone, but no luck. Any ideas? I'm at a loss. I should note, that after authentication I also call the Google Drive api from within my app, and that doesn't appear to cause any problems. So far as I can tell, it's just `gapi.auth2` that's causing issues.

The code I'm using which successfully authenticates with Google

```
const googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

googleAuth.then(() => {
  googleAuth.signIn().then((result) => {
    this.signinSuccess();
  });
})
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @Edric There are zero errors in the console :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe I used it as follows in one project:

```
  googleAuth.signIn().then((result) => {
    this.signinSuccess();
  });
```

Basically I don't have `googleAuth.then(() =>` because googleAuth is not a promise.

Comment: I've tried many different log in permutations, including through different methods like `gapi.auth2.authorize()`. I don't _think_ that the problem has to do with the way I log in. And again, the login is successful. But good to know that you've used the `googleAuth` javascript API successfully with Angular. It definitely _feels_ like I've done something wrong with the way I set up the code. This all being said, after about 10 hours I gave up on it and went on without Google (which was, luckily, an option for me)